# How to divide a class project having a part in dlls and another in code (tricky question)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, c#-3.0, compilation

currently I trying to do something a bit tricky which I don't really know if it's possible to do.

I have a class project and I want to divide it in two sections, "Core" and "Client specific developments". And my client wants the source code of this project but I don't want to deliver the source code of the "Core" section, I just want to give him the source of "Client specific developments".

So to demonstrate a practical case let's imagine that I have a partial class named "User" that have two methods "CreateUser" and "CreateUserForClientSite". So "CreateUser" method will be located in "Core" section and "CreateUserForClientSite" will extend "CreateUser" with specific requirements for my client site (remember this methods may NOT be static, so C# 3.0 class extend feature is pointless in this case). If I have the "Core" section in dll can I extend a partial class present in the dll?

Now let's imagine another scenario. What if "Core" have methods that depend on "Client specific developments" classes, and the other way around? Since I can't do circular reference between projects, how can I manage that (is possible)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the partial classes - you must have all the parts of the partial class available at compile time. You just split definition of a class in several files, but it is still a type that belongs to one assembly.

Thus you cannot compile dll with one part and then reference that assembly in another project and add more methods to the partial class.

I suggest to replace partial classes with inheritance in your case, if possible.

More on partial classes in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28VS.80%29.aspx) (look at "Restrictions" section).

Regarding the circular references - you'll have to redesign your object model if splitting into two assemblies leads to this problem. Usually, this indicates flaws in the model that should be fixed anyway.

You can define interfaces in the core assembly to break the circular reference. And implement the interfaces in client specific assembly. Take a look at this article for example - [How to get rid of circular references in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/03/18/398601.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will have to think of another approach to solve my problem.